# Globalization não funciona ao fazer deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Fiz o deploy de uma aplicação ASP.NET em uma máquina localizada no centro dos Estados Unidos e agora a mesma se comporta como sendo americana mesmo com a instrução abaixo no arquivo web.config:

```
<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
```

Vale ressaltar que essa configuração está no arquivo `Views/web.config` e não no arquivo `Web.config` que fica localizado na pasta raiz do projeto.

Comment: Mas não deveria estar no web.config da raiz? Não está por quê?

Comment: Não está na raiz pois em ambiente de desenvolvimento a configuração estava funcionando perfeitamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa colocar essa declaração no `web.config` da raiz da sua aplicação, dentro da seção `<configuration>` e `<system.web>`.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ja conferiu qual a linguagem esta sendo usanda no seu navegador?

intenert explorer:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Chrome:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]